# convert base64 to image in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have written some code for capturing image using nodejs and I have used **npm base64-to-image**, but it's not working properly. Below is the code:

```
var base64Str = policyObj.image;                    
var path ='public/images/';
var optionalObj = {'fileName': 'policyimg', 'type':'png'};
base64ToImage(base64Str,path,optionalObj);
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem:

> "*Error:* Invalid base64 string"
>
> **To debug**, try replacing 1st line with: `var base64Str = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==";`

Another:

> An incorrect path as a *logical error*, runs code without error but not saving the image file as it should. Ie, if the path points to a non-existant directory, misspelled directory or a inaccessable directory.
>
> **To debug**, try replacing 2nd line with `var path ='./';` so it will save in the script directory. Note that '/' leads to no file saved, and an empty string leads to error "Missing mandatory arguments..."

Comment: 1st solution what you have mentioned is right. But the problem what i am facing is , my image is not getting supported

Comment: may be you are saving a  image by wrong extesnion example saving  .png file as .jpg @SRK

Comment: actually. that's not the issue. I am giving the proper extension, but i wonder there is something else is going wrong. @shivshankar

Comment: Is that a message you get from trying to open the saved file, then probably it's something bad with policyObj.image you got from somewhere. To find out what, start with `console.log(typeof policyObj.image)` to see if it is a _string_.  Next, try `console.log(policyObj.image)`. Look at the output if it starts with `data:image/xxx;base64,` where xxx is the image format. It's not uncommon that data-urls like this get misformatted in the header or additional citation marks, and it's possible to "repair" the string if that's the case.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to fix or replace the code that produced the string. To make sure that is what ought to be done, copy the logged string without the surrounding " or ', paste it into chrome address-bar or some [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/), try to fix the header if needed, then see if there is the image shown.

Comment: response what i am getting is correct.  i guess there is some minute mistake. I'll figure it out. `policyobj.image` is not saved file, it's an request what i am taking from database @RikkuBölske

Comment: Good luck! More about dataURLs, see [http://dataurl.net](http://dataurl.net), more on setting using file-paths in node: [https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/#paths](cross-platform paths). Also, check the source code of [base64-to-image](https://github.com/helensy/base64-to-image/blob/master/index.js) to study how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// target is path where you want to save file example /upload/filename.png
fs.writeFile(target, new Buffer(base64Str, "base64"), function (err) {
     if(err)   console.log(err);
      console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Comment: i implemented your logic , but i am getting  has **Missing mandatory arguments base64 string and/or path string** near base64ToImage

Comment: `var base64Str = policyObj.image;     
var path ='public/images';
var optionalObj = {'fileName': 'policyimg', 'type':'png'};
base64ToImage(base64Str,path,optionalObj); 
fs.writeFile(path, new Buffer(base64Str, "base64"), function (err) {
        if(err)   
         console.log('Error:' + err);
        else {
     console.log('The file has been saved!');
        }
});`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.